# Ruby Binary Read and Write Rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm trying to export my database to a file, then be able to read it back later. This works perfectly fine when the contents are in JSON, but I've recently decided to compress the data and when I export the data it has be in binary.

My question is how do I export data in binary to a file (OSX operating system), then be able to read it back and process it row by row to either do analysis or repopulate another database.

---

My solution to this problem was to encode the compression as Base64 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and then add my own marker to split the row "..;;;;.." for example.

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite? Use the built-in export/import capabilities, instead of something you write yourself. It'll be faster, well tested and optimized.

Comment: I'm using DynamoDB where I need to save as a compressed file so that it gives me as much space under their 64 KB limit as possible and my ORM is hand-made.

Answer (score 3):

It's odd that you'd want to export the data from the database to a file, then read it in row-by-row for further processing. That's a waste of CPU time and disk space.

Instead, iterate over the needed database rows and process them directly.

Comment: I am using DynamoDB and I need to export the data to back it up and it's cheaper to do multiple local iterations (although slower than what we need for web speeds) than to process on Dynamo itself.